# Path arc is thicker than line arc when drawing on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I'm creating a custom View which draws a simple line with a rounded corner using canvas and i can't get the line in the corner to have the same thickness as the straight parts.
The path is defined in the onSizeChanged method.

this is how my view looks like:

[image: Line]

Here is the view

```
public class CanvasView extends View {

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;
Context context;

public CanvasView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    context = c;
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

public CanvasView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
    context = c;
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if(mBitmap == null) {

        RectF rectf = new RectF(w - w / 2, h - w / 2, w, h);
        mPath.moveTo(w, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(w, h - w / 2);
        mPath.arcTo(rectf, 0, 90);
        mPath.lineTo(0, h);

        mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBitmapPaint.setDither(true);
        mBitmapPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.siminn_warm_gray));
        mBitmapPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mBitmapPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mBitmapPaint);

}
}
```

Comment: Why are you drawing a bitmap instead of drawing a line?

Comment: the `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);` is useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're drawing with canvas you have to take in account view padding. onSizeChanged method gives you the witdh and the height of the view without padding. To get padding you can use `getPaddingTop()`, `getPaddingBottom()`, `getPaddingStart()` and `getPaddingEnd()` function in your View class.
This would be the code considering padding:

```java
@Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        int realWidth = w - (getPaddingStart() + getPaddingEnd());
        int realHeight = h - (getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            RectF rectf = new RectF(realWidth - realWidth / 2, realHeight - realWidth / 2, realWidth, realHeight);
            mPath.moveTo(realWidth, getPaddingTop());
            mPath.lineTo(realWidth, realHeight - realWidth / 2);
            mPath.arcTo(rectf, 0, 90);
            mPath.lineTo(getPaddingStart(), realHeight);

            mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mBitmapPaint.setDither(true);
            mBitmapPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.siminn_warm_gray));
            mBitmapPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mBitmapPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, i was drawing along the edge of the canvas which had the effect of showing only half of the line. I moved the lines a little bit from the edge and it's working